# Add custom parameter in order's item in rest api magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

In magento 2, I have show specific custom option in order's item parallel to product name, sku.. rather than in parent_item array. I have only show in api not need to save in database.

[image]

Please anybody can help into this.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, do you know extension_attributes? Would this option fit your needs ?

Comment: Extension attribute working for order but I need to add parameter in order item. If an order have 5 items then I have to show custom option for all those 5 items.  Please share any example which can help me.